# Declare First Row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to declare my first row since it is vary.
Eg below my first row at row 11 because my consecutive number one is at row 11.
It is vary sometime at row 10, 9 and other. How to declare .

For the last row , i understand how to do :

```
lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2
```

[image]

Comment: If the value `1` always refers to the first row (by your logic) then I suppose you can use `Find` method on column A?

Comment: @RaymondWu A bit risky to look for a `1` by `Find`. I would suggest to look for `Function Manifold` and `Offset(1, 0)` from there or at least something more unique than a `1`.

Comment: I see, hold on i am searching for other thread

Comment: Alternatively use *Named Ranges* and give "line one" a name like *"FirstLine"* so you can access it with `Range("FirstLine")`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I do agree with you on that but given that `Function Manifold` can well be a "dynamic" header.. that might not be reliable too (which OP needs to clarify, what is the consistent format despite the different rows it can end up with?)

Comment: I agree with @Pᴇʜ. Naming the range is the best option. Less code...

Comment: Meaning by @Pᴇʜ , it is something similar with "lastrow" that i am using as above ?

Comment: Can you do `xlup` again from `lastrow`? if A is always populated, I can't see the image.

Comment: @Biha no what I mean is creating a named range: See [Creating and using named ranges](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_365/tips/creating_and_using_named_ranges.html).

Answer (score 0):

### Determine a Special First Row

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetSpecialFirstRowTEST()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim firstR As Long: firstR = GetSpecialFirstRow(ws)
    
    If firstR = 0 Then ' this will never happen if you are sure that there's a 1
        MsgBox "Could not determine the first row.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MsgBox "The first row is '" & firstR & "'.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

### EDIT

- Pᴇʜ has convinced me (made some valid points) to improve the function.

```vb
Function GetSpecialFirstRow( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet) _
As Long
    Const ProcName As String = "GetSpecialFirstRow"
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' e.g. when 'ws Is Nothing'
    
    ' First occurrence of number 1 in column 'A'.
    Dim rIndex As Variant: rIndex = Application.Match(1, ws.Columns("A"), 0)
    If IsError(rIndex) Then
        GetSpecialFirstRow = 0
    Else
        GetSpecialFirstRow = rIndex
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

- Note that `GetSpecialFirstRow = IIf(IsError(rIndex), 0, rIndex)` is less efficient (slower).

**Old Function**

```
Function GetSpecialFirstRow( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet) _
As Long
    ' First occurrence of number 1 in column 'A'.
    On Error Resume Next
        GetSpecialFirstRow = Application.Match(1, ws.Columns("A"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: `Application.Match` does not throw an exception. You need to use `Application.WorksheetFunkction.Match` to get an exception or check `IsError(Application.Match())`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: The function is `As Long`, an error value doesn't 'fit' in a `Long` hence a type mismatch error will occur i.e. the function returns `0`.

Comment: Ah my bad I missed the `Long`. Still I would avoid unstructured error handling if I can and use `IsError` instead. Unstructured error handling is generally less efficient. Here it is easily avoidable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really really don't get it.

Comment: `Application.Match` is similar to Excel's `Match`: with the last argument set to 0, it will try to return the index (position) of the first occurrence of a value in a row or a column. Since we are dealing in a column (column `A`), it will return the row index of the column i.e. the row (number). If the item is not found, it will return an error value (not raise an error). You can test the result of `Application.Match` by using `IsError` or `IsNumeric` in an `If` statement. To conclude, the function will return the row number or 0 (if not found).